# How to draw this scheme in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphdrawing

Do you know if it is possible to draw such scheme in latex? What  package should I use? Do you know examples close to mine?Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Yes. Hard to say: which drawing packages have you tried? It depends what you mean by 'close'. Your tags suggest you prefer TikZ. Whether or no, have a go with your poison of choice and post a Minimal Working Example when you get stuck asking for help to overcome a specific problem. The manual has several tutorials. Note that I have no idea what this is meant to be. Check CTAN in case there's something specialised.

Comment: I'd say Tikz is your best option. Or maybe it's my love for it that's speaking.

Comment: I am absolutely new at Latex. I've searched for working examples how to draw this picture and I know how to draw circles,lines,grid but how to incorporate all of these together - I have no idea. I need some clues how to put everything together in a way I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you said you know some TikZ commands, here's a starting point. Feel free to comment if you do not understand something or if you get stuck.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    double/.style={shorten <= 3mm, shorten >= 2mm}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[red!50!black] (0,0) .. controls (3,2.5) and (5,-2.5) .. (7,0)
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \pos using ((10/5)*.\x)] in {0,...,5}{ 
        node[pos=\pos, circle, fill=red!50!black] (a\x) {} 
    };

\draw (-1,-2) coordinate (O) -- (8,-2);

\foreach \y in {0,...,5}{
    \draw[double, -{Latex}] (a\y.south east) -- (a\y.south east|-O);
    \draw[double, -{Latex}] (a\y.south west|-O) -- (a\y.south west);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```